# D3 exit().remove() on stack area chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm having some trouble with the `exit().remove()` function in a stacked area chart I am creating.

`JSFiddle` here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/eguE5/)

I have functionality where the user can `enable`/`disable` the data in the chart by clicking on the legend rectangle/color.  I know that the data is being updated based on console messages and the Y axis changing scale, but the data in the chart does not change.  For instance if the user deselects the `Failed` category the orange layer should disappear and the Failed and Passed layers should re-adjust.

The issue appears to be in lines 214 to 234 in the fiddle, specifically where I am calling `exit().remove()`:

```
// filter the data
var updatedData = dataSeries.filter(function(d) {
    if(d.vis === "1"){
        return d;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
});

stack.values(function(d) { return d.values; });

layer = stack(updatedData);

main_layer.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layer);

main_layer
    .attr("d", function(d) { return main_area(d.values); });

main_layer.exit().remove();
```

The error I am getting is Object [object Array] has no method `exit`  I have tried changing the selectAll to just a select, but that also produces the same error.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a breakpoint right before the `.exit()` call and see what `main_layer` is? From the error message, it would appear it's been reassigned to something other than a D3 selection.

Comment: You need to operate on the selection, not on `main_layer` -- `var sel = main_layer.selectAll(".layer").data(layer); sel.exit().remove();`.

Comment: Added a debugging statement to the fiddle.  Lars, I also updated with your solution, but am getting some odd results.  I'll try to debug what is going on.

Comment: I made some additional updates.  It is very odd; the filtered data is still coming through as expected, but when it gets to line 234 where it calls d.key all the keys are the same (i.e.: all 'Failed') instead of three different keys.

Comment: I finally got this working...will post the answer in a minute.  Lars, thanks for the help - your suggestion helped get me past one of the major issues I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working.  The code below updates the layers correctly:

```
// filter the data
var updatedData = dataSeries.filter(function(d) {
    if(d.vis === "1"){
        return d;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
});

stack(updatedData);

var sel = main_layer.select(".layer");

sel
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.key + " layer"; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { 
        if(d.vis === "1") {
            return z(i);   
        }
        else return null;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) { 
        if(d.vis === "1") {
            return main_area(d.values); 
        }
        else return null;
    });
```